# Custom Preference not storing value in SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I've written a custom `DialogPreference`, containing two `NumberPickers`. In `"onDialogClose"` I want the values from each to be combined and then stored in `SharedPreferences`, using "persistLong".

The preference works just fine, and everything gets called as expected, but when I try to retrieve the value from `SharedPreferences` it seems like nothing has been stored using the key I provided.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Post some code. Especially reading and storing the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not be providing the right `context`, that is place where you retrieve the `SharedPreferences` might be using a different context than the place where you store the new preferences.

A much easier approach would be to use a single `PreferenceHelper` class throughout the application to retrieve and store values.

```
package in.example;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class PreferencesHelper {
    private SharedPreferences prefs;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    // Class constants.

    public PreferencesHelper(Context context) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        editor = prefs.edit();
    }

    public static PreferencesHelper getInstance(Context context) {
        return new PreferencesHelper(context);
    }

    public Boolean getBoolean(String key) {
        return prefs.getBoolean(key, false);
    }

    public void setBoolean(String key, Boolean value) {
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getString(String key) {
        return prefs.getString(key, "");
    }

    public void setString(String key, String value) {
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public int getInt(String key) {
        return prefs.getInt(key, 0);
    }

    public void setInt(String key, int value) {
        editor.putInt(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

}
```

Now you can easily get an instance of this class by calling `PreferencesHelper.getInstance(context)` and then simply call its methods to store or retrieve values.

> Note. The above sample class returns an empty string, false for
>   boolean values and 0 for int values, if no value are set or found for
>   a given preference key.

Comment: It seems like two different Contexts was the issue! Thank you very much!

Comment: To be exact getDefaultSharedPreferences returns a singleton inside a process - whatever context you pass it inside the process does not matter. See : http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/33539/27480 for my wrapper

Comment: Also - make prefs and editor _final_. This will make your class thread safe. And to have some lines cut off chain the calls like `editor.putInt(key, value).commit();`. Finally since you provide a factory make the cstor private - although you could make your class "static" maybe

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D really really thank you very much, these were really very good learnings you have just introduced me to :)

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D i will keep these in mind with my future programs and wrappers too. :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `context.getApplicationContext()` for the SharedPreferences context?